# Recognizing regular camera instead of infrared

Tags: webcam, camera

I've installed Ubuntu Linux (latest version as of a couple weeks ago) on a Dell laptop, and instead of getting a normal camera image of myself in apps like Skype, I'm getting what looks like an infrared camera image.  It looks like I'm in the sights of some sniper's night scope.

I'm guessing the Dell laptop must have a regular camera for imagery and an infrared camera for things like facial recognition.

How do I get Ubuntu to use the right camera?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please also provide the model part number from the serial number sticker, or the service tag, so we can confirm what kind of camera's i n that PC. Click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment as that's our channel to you. All facts of the PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Change the camera to `/dev/video0` in Skype.